# Exporting a class to use in my parent file

Tags: webpack

So I have a simple Errors classes in `Errors.js`

```
export default class Errors
{
    constructor() {
        this.errors = {};
    }

    has(field) {
        return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
    }

    any() {
        return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 1;
    }

    get(field) {
        if(this.errors[field]){
            return this.errors[field][0]
        }
    }

    record(errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    clear(field) {
        delete this.errors[field];
    }
}
```

In my app.js I am trying to call the Errors class to use its functions, like so:

```
import Errors from './errors.js';
```

When I try using the Errors and console logging the following:

```
console.log(Errors)
console.log(Errors.record({'name': 'test'}))
```

I get the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDXvd.png

How can I access the Errors class in the app.js and all files I include in my app.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes in javascript follow the same way that classes work on another languages such as java.

Trying to access `Error.record` tells the engine to access a static method inside the Error class. Is that what you want to do? I don't think so.

Just follow the same way that classes works on another languages.

```
import Errors from './errors.js';
const Error = new Errors();
console.log(Error.record({}));
```

Comment: Makes sense, but how come with some packages I can just import and it works without initiating the class?

Comment: Well, good question. Can you give an example and we see what is different?

Comment: For example with vue, you can import it, then access the Vue.Component before you've created the class instance: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Oh, you talking about defining a component and `<myComponent></myComponent>` on """Html"""?

Comment: If so, that is a specificity of vue, i have no idea how vue accomplishes that in the back. But given pure javascript, my answer still valid.